# Critique: How can I improve my logo?

Tags: logo, critique

I am a noob to photoshop, however I have been able to make this, I have a liking for minimalism :
[image]

More about the company:
Aims to help people by raising money

How can I improve this, make this perfect?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me that black color feels slightly eye hurting, because when we look at this then it seems that all the attention is drawn towards the black color.

And the font goes against the minimalism. I have changed the color slightly and got this.

[image]

Comment: Hey! definitely looks better now. Do you have a .psd file for this that you could share with me? Because I have no idea where to start to get those shadows on each object and the font too. You will make my work easier. Thanks!

Comment: You could mail it to me psdsamflynn@mailinator.com Thanks

Comment: Can you put it in a google drive folder and then email the link to me? I'll be ever so grateful.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZLkOmwf_AhbU5INF9YQUZHY00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Which font did you use for the text?

Comment: Fixedsys Regular

Comment: I'd ask: how does a heavily pixelated font reflect the concept of 'human'?

Comment: I'd be glad if you suggest some other font. I used this because it looked good even at different scale.

Answer (score 3):

Work on scale. The type vs. the logomark, for example. How would this look printed at 50%? You'd hardly be able to read the type.

Why the overlap? Why the shadow? These aren't bad, per se, but when you say you like minimalism, these would typically be seen as superfluous to that.

What's the thought behind the typeface? do you feel the loose script face works well with the very geometric mark?

Comment: Okay, I'll work on the scale. I though it still looked minimalistic even with shadows, if I remove them the logo just looks so bland. I thought the typeface loooked good but I cant say as I lack experience in designing. Please do  suggest how would you do it. Thanks!